# Autorotate problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, background, autorotate

I want autorotate in my application but there is a problem, the background in portrait mode is not the same as in landscape mode.
Is there anybody who can give me a short example how to solve this problem, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you write your UIView-Subclass in code or are you using a xib?
How differs the background-color? Is it streched, is there a white border, somehow similar or completely different?
Does your view also looks different if you load your view in landscape mode or is it just after rotating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the method

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

in the ViewController that contains the background. Query the interfaceOrientation property on this ViewController to find out what is the current orientation and set the background according to the value (which is of type UIInterfaceOrientation).